# Invalid GeoJSON for polygon

Tags: json, google-maps, geocoding, geojson

I am trying to plot a polygon on a google map using geojson.  Here is the PHP code where I am trying to build the polygon using four bounds values return from the query result array:

```
$arr3_poly = Array(
         "type" => "Polygon",
         "coordinates" => Array()
    );  
    foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) {  
          $arr3_poly["coordinates"][] = Array(
          floatval($row['v3_bounds_sw_lat']),        
          floatval($row['v3_bounds_sw_lng']),
          floatval($row['v3_bounds_ne_lat']),
          floatval($row['v3_bounds_ne_lng']),
      );
    }
```

When I then do `json_encode($arr3_poly, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`, this is the resulting output:

```
{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
    [
        43.8526377,
        -79.0499898,
        43.8526509,
        -79.0499877
    ],
    [
        43.8526546,
        -79.0501977,
        43.8526678,
        -79.0501957
    ],
    [
        43.8526716,
        -79.0504057,
        43.8526848,
        -79.0504037
    ]
]
}
```

There must be something wrong with this geojson because when I try to validate it at [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/) it returns with this error saying `Failed to validate field 'coordinates' list schema.`:

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Each coordinate should be one pair [lat, lng], not 4 numbers

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Considering that I have 2 pairs of [lat, lng] values, as in `[sw_lat, sw_lng]` and `[ne_lat, ne_lng]`, does it matter which coordinate pair I use?

Comment: Where did those values come from? They sound more like a bounds of something rather than a coordinate.

Comment: That's an insightful comment.  Those values are the result of the json response to the google geocoding API.  The values that come back are: location, location_type, viewport and bounds.  I though I could use these value to plot the property in question, but now I'm thinking that is not what they were intended for.  That being the case, what are these different values intended to be used for?  What can I do with them, now that I have them?  Thanks.

Comment: Those values are defined in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results) `location contains the geocoded latitude,longitude value. For normal address lookups, this field is typically the most important.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/) (changed your points slightly to make it not look like a straight line):

```
{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
    [
        [43.8526377,-79.0499898],
        [43.854,-79.051],
        [43.8526716,-79.0504057],
        [43.8526377,-79.0499898]
    ]
  ]
}
```

However, looking closer at that map, they are in Antarctica, you probably wanted this, which is in Canada, near Toronto:

```
{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
    [
        [-79.0499898,43.8526377],
        [-79.051,43.854],
        [-79.0504057,43.8526716],
        [-79.0499898,43.8526377]
    ]
  ]
}
```

[GeoJSON coordinates](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions):

> The order of elements must follow x, y, z order (longitude, latitude, altitude for 
>   coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system).

Which is the opposite order from a google.maps.LatLng object (that is Latitude, Longitude).